# Can't install Angry ipscan in ubuntu LTS 20.4

Tags: ip, network-monitoring

I can't install **Angry ipscan** in ubuntu.When I tried to install it showed this:[Error_Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIfs6.png)

But I have already installed Oracle Java JDK. Screenshot:[Java_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipLcO.png)

I am not good with nmap or arp-scan & I have already used **Angry Ipscan** for about 2 years with **GUI**. So if you have any alternatives,please make sure that it has **GUI** or show me the process of installing my preferred package

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting is because you are not having the specific java. The solution is to install `open-jdk-8` as it is a prerequisite. Therefore run the following commands to install it.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk
```

Answer (score 0):

do this:

```
wget https://github.com/angryip/ipscan/releases/download/3.7.6/ipscan_3.7.6_all.deb
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre gdebi
sudo gdebi ipscan_3.7.6_all.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. It worked for me after i followed below procedure. [Problem with openjdk-8-jre upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1289420/problem-with-openjdk-8-jre-upgrade) and then followed the commands mentioned here.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).